# Cannot instantiate interface DrupalStreamWrapperInterface

Tags: 7, stream-wrappers

I am trying to replace drupal_realpath with [realpath](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21stream_wrappers.inc/function/DrupalStreamWrapperInterface%3A%3Arealpath/7.x). What I did is

```
$stream_wrapper = new DrupalStreamWrapperInterface();
$file_path = $stream_wrapper->realpath($img_path);
```

But it gives me this error: `Cannot instantiate interface DrupalStreamWrapperInterface`. Any idea how do I use DrupalStreamWrapperInterface::realpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to create an object of a [PHP Interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), which is not allowed in PHP. You can only create objects from a [PHP Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

To solve your issue, something like this might work:

```
$wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($img_path);
if (is_object($wrapper)) {
  $file_path = $wrapper->realpath();
}
```